# JTable JComboBox wrong first item name

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I added a Swing `JComboBox` to a `JTable`, but the label of my first item is  always `javax.swing.JComboBox(...`

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE : this is my code :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableSelection extends JPanel {

    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);

    public TableSelection() {
        model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        labels.add("");
        for (int i = 1; i < 10 + 1; i++) {
            labels.add("" + (i - 1));
        }

        model.addColumn("Column");
        model.addColumn("Column2");

        JComboBox<String> jcombo1 = new JComboBox<String>();
        jcombo1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(labels.toArray()));
        jcombo1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jcombo1.setSelectedIndex(1);
        DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(jcombo1);

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(editor);

        model.addRow(new JComboBox[]{jcombo1});

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(560, 300));
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("TableSelection");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new TableSelection());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to show more code in your question. It sounds like you are calling a toString() on the JComboBox....

Comment: Can you post what's inside the table cell? It says `invalid`, there might be a hint... And probably if you post a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be better than just a part of your code.

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)

Comment: Kudos for posting an [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The essential problem is here:

```
model.addRow(new JComboBox[]{combo});
```

Don't add components to the table model. Instead, let the [renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) handle the job, using "a label that displays the object's string value." Your initial label, an empty `String`, is shown below.

```
model.addRow(new String[]{labels.get(0)});
```

[image]

In addition:

- Code to the interface, e.g. `List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>()`
- Start on the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Code as tested:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableSelection extends JPanel {

    private final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    private final JTable table = new JTable(model);

    public TableSelection() {
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
        labels.add("");
        for (int i = 1; i < 10 + 1; i++) {
            labels.add("" + (i - 1));
        }
        model.addColumn("Column 1");
        model.addColumn("Column 2");

        JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>();
        combo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(labels.toArray()));
        combo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        combo.setSelectedIndex(1);
        DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(combo);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(editor);
        //model.addRow(new JComboBox[]{combo});
        model.addRow(new String[]{labels.get(0)});
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(320, 120));
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("TableSelection");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.add(new TableSelection());
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're adding the `JComboBox` to your table model instead of the actual data.

Instead of this:

```
model.addRow(new JComboBox[]{jcombo1});
```

Do this:

```
model.addRow(new Object[]{labels});
```

There's a full example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableRenderDemoProject/src/components/TableRenderDemo.java)

Comment: The [complete code as tested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34073510/230513) works for me.