# how to get current position of selected cell (JComboBox )in JTable

Tags: java, swing

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTable table;
private JComboBox<String> jcbtest;
private DefaultTableModel tablemodel;

    jcbtest=new JComboBox<String>();
    jcbtest.addItem("item1");
    jcbtest.addItem("item2");
    jcbtest.addItem("item3");
    jcbtest.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int curi=table.getSelectedRow();
            int curj=table.getSelectedColumn();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "actionListener:"+curi+"    "+curj);

        }
    });

    jcbtest.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent e){
            int curi=table.getSelectedRow();
            int curj=table.getSelectedColumn();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "itemstateChanged:"+curi+"  "+curj);               
        }
    });

    table = new JTable();String title[]={"姓名", "部门", "职位"};
    tablemodel=new DefaultTableModel(title, 3);
    table = new JTable(tablemodel){
        private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
        public boolean isCellEditable( int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
            if( rowIndex == getRowCount() - 1 ){
                DefaultTableModel dtm=(DefaultTableModel)dataModel;
                dtm.addRow(new String[]{"","",""});
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(jcbtest));

    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
```

First time to select, it shows no selected cell

After that, it gave me the position of previous operation

How to get current selected cell position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a [`DefaultCellEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html) with a `JComboBox<String>`, as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34073510/230513), and use it as a [cell editor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). When applied to an editable cell, each cell's current selection will be stored in the `TableModel`.

> What should I do to get the selected-cell's position?

The `JComboBox` is used *only* as a [cell editor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), and it's selection index is meaningless except when *in use* as an editor. At all other times, the chosen value in stored in the `TableModel`. Given a particular value, you can use the `getIndexOf()` method of the editor's [`DefaultComboBoxModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) to determine the position it had when in use as an editor.

Comment: When i select a cell the first time,the return value of getSelectedRow() and getSelectedColumn() are wrong, and the second time I click the cell, I can get the right position. What should I do to get the selected-cell's position? I have ran your code and it has the same suitation.

Comment: I've elaborated above.